# Generate the Unlock key

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I am using WIX and C# custom Action to unlock the products.
We have planned to modify our unlock key like (34450-ee33-8736333-30393) from old style.
Could you please let me know which algorithm is suitable for this? And it would be useful to provide online materials to learn this.
Please let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the various cryptography classes in System.Net.Security and System.Net.Security.Cryptography. I've especially used classes like MD5CryptoServiceProvider to compute the hash of a binary block or file and output a digest similar to one you have mentioned. You can then match the system generated vs user input keys to activate/unlock your software.

Here is a sample from one of my cryptography endeavours:

```
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
            byte[] checksum = null;
            if (optMD5.IsChecked==true)
            {
                MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();//.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                checksum=new byte[1024];
                checksum = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
            }
            else if (optSHA1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                SHA1 sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                checksum = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("No option selected.");
                return;
            }
            //string schecksum = BitConverter.ToString(checksum);//ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(checksum);

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < checksum.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(checksum[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string.
            //return sb.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("checksum-1 = " + sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "checksum-2 = " + txtChecksum.Text);
```